# Prioritize Asana tags

Tags: asana

I have created a bunch of tags that I assign to the tasks. For example, to what project it relates or who else is involved and so on. Additionally I use tags to prioritize the tasks. There's one called `blocker` which is red, a normal on, and so on. Unfortunately, Asana only shows 2 tags in the list, sometimes my coloured tags are hidden, when there are 3 or more tags.

Is there a way to prioritize which tag Asana displays first?

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests. Asana shows the tags ordered alphabetically. The tags have higher priority than the projects, so they'll show up before everything else near the task. From my tests you can see only two tags near the task.

My solution: prepend a character to the important tags categories so they'll show up before every other tag or project name. For instance: `@printer-office` or `*high-priority` or `*blocker`. Maybe a bit late but I hope this can help.